# Slow input even with useTransition()

Tags: reactjs, react-18, usetransition

I'm playing with the new `useTransition()` hook added in React 18.

I created an app highlighting the matching names. If it matches, the item gets green, otherwise red. Here how I did it:

```
import { useState, useTransition } from 'react';
import people from './people.json'; // 20k items

const PeopleList = ({ people, highlight, isLoading }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Ready'}</div>
            <ol>
                {people.map((name, index) => (
                    <li
                        key={index}
                        style={{
                            color: (
                                name.toLowerCase().includes(highlight)
                                ? 'lime'
                                : 'red'
                            )
                        }}
                    >
                        {name}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ol>
        </>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    const [needle, setNeedle] = useState('');
    const [highlight, setHighlight] = useState('');
    const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={needle}
                onChange={event => {
                    setNeedle(event.target.value);
                    startTransition(
                        () => setHighlight(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
                    );
                }}
            />
            <PeopleList
                people={people}
                highlight={highlight}
                isLoading={isPending}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The JSON file contains an array of 20k people. Unfortunately, the `useTransition()` doesn't seem to improve performance in this case. Whether I use it or not, typing in the input is very laggy, making about a 0.5s delay between each character.

My first thought was that maybe such a big DOM tree would cause a delay in the input, but it doesn't seem the case in a raw HTML page.

Why doesn't `useTransition()` make typing smooth in my example?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you also using `createRoot`?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah is it still required in React 18? It only was when `useTransition()` was in an experimental state, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: May I ask where the `needle` state is used? Could you remove that for now?

Comment: @androidavid it's used as the input's value.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because your app is running in React 17 mode.

Source: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#deprecations

> react-dom: ReactDOM.render has been deprecated. Using it will warn and run your app in React 17 mode.

Comment: I checked and it seems I actually use React 18 in a proper mode. The `index.js` says `const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));`. I created this app via create-react-app right before checking how `useTransition()` works.

Comment: Another possible issue is that your React state is too high. https://epicreact.dev/improve-the-performance-of-your-react-forms/

Answer (score -1):

How about wrapping PeopleList component in a memo.

As far as my understanding goes. Everytime when setNeedle is being called `<App/>` component is rerendering and then `<PeopleList/>` is also rerendering even though nothing changed in `<PeopleList/>` component.

Comment: This is neither point of the question nor how `useMemo()` works.

Comment: @RoboRobok have a look at my [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-saha-6z35dr?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).